# Dropdownlist does not return the selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, model

I am not able to set the value to the dropdownlist after its retrieval in the model.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.EntityFrontType)
                    .DataTextField("Text")
                    .DataValueField("Value")
                    .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>()
                    {
                        new SelectListItem(){
                            Text = "Company" , Value = "Company"
                        },
                        new SelectListItem(){
                            Text = "Fund" , Value = "Fund"
                        }
                    }).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 30em" })
                    )
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EntityFrontType)
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the value explicitly: `.Value(Model.EntityFrontType)`?

Comment: It worked. Thank you soo much